unable to reach minikube ip on linux using docker driver
I've installed minikube on a Ubuntu 22.04 box, and I'm unable to reach services exposed through an ingress.
I'm able to access the services starting a tunnel or a proxy, but I'd like to avoid this.
I've created an ingress
kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS                 ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   nginx   hello-world.example   192.168.49.2   80      21s

192.168.49.2 is not reachable, network traffic has no way of reaching that destination.
I am able to see the docker network bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "minikube",
        "Id": "bec41f74d2d5eff355cde6584295d447babbe8fb37b6ac93d8266705e270947e",
        "Created": "2024-07-27T08:33:51.03028014+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.49.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.49.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "e6a419dda2b4e69fea43fdea4aed40bf43a773cd558e19e34caec90d7aa597d5": {
                "Name": "minikube",
                "EndpointID": "f0d6eebbfc5edbc25a1fd61d36bbb61b2e4dc74296b057f8b347ff3716b981c0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:31:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.49.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "--icc": "",
            "--ip-masq": "",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io": "true",
            "name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io": "minikube"
        }
    }
]

On another box, I was able to get everything working, and in there I see a minikube bridge network interface by calling ifconfig on the host, and a network route created. So there must be something wrong with my host set-up, but I'm struggling to find out what.

Are you sure minikube has not already mapped port 80/443 to the host machine with the firewall? What happens if you just try and use the host's IP address (make sure port 80/443 is open on the host as well)

192.168.49.2 is should be reachable; it would be reachable via the docker bridge associated with the docker network on which the container is deployed.

thank you @hardillb, I did indeed double check, and no, it's not open. telnet 127.0.0.1 80 (or 443), connection refused

In that case at the output of ip l and ip -4 a to the question so we know if the bridge is linked to the host

Thanks to @hardillb suggestion, I can see that the docker0 interface was down.
Output of ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:XX:XX:XX:8e:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:XX:XX:XX:56:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: br-fb0f9229b18a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:XX:XX:f7:XX:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none

Output of ip -4 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 37.27.XXX.XXX/32 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    inet 100.96.185.17/32 scope global tailscale0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

By simply calling sudo ip link set dev docker0 up and restarting minikube, I'm now able to access services exposed on 192.168.49.2
